# Analytical results for sum of normally distributed random variables with e.g. sorting?

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

Assume I have bolts and holes, both following a normal distribution with
$$\mu_B = 90 mm,  \sigma_B = 8 mm$$
$$\mu_L = 100 mm, \sigma_L = 4 mm$$
As we know that the sum also follows a normal distribution we can calculate 
the probability that a randomly picked bolt fits into a randomly picked hole:
$\Phi((90-100)/\sqrt{8^2+4^2})$ which is about 13%. This is clear to me.

My question: What if we skip the "randomly picked" and allow e.g. for sorting. Can we still calculate the probability how many times a bolt will not fit in a hole? Or how can we achieve the lowest failure rate? Is there any way to calculate the result? We could e.g. allow for sorting...

Comment: A simulation using sorting indicates, that failure rate drops to about 0.6%! The following code shows the situation using R-code:

```
expected_failure_rate <- pnorm((90-100)/sqrt(8^2+4^2), 0, 1)

n <- 1000000
B <- rnorm(n, 90, 8)
L <- rnorm(n, 100, 4)
failure_rate <- 1 - sum(L > B)/n

B_sort <- sort(B)
L_sort <- sort(L)
failure_rate_sort <- 1 - sum(L_sort > B_sort)/n
```

Comment: Are your failure defined as L $\le$ B?

Comment: @user158565: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: OK. In simulation, you cannot sort. just `failure_rate_sort <- 1 - sum(L > B)/n` see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting only is not optimal, you can also reject the largest bolts and the smallest holes.

```
k <- 2000
improved_failure_rate <- 1-sum(L_sort[k:n] > B_sort[1:(n-k+1)])/n
```

This improves the failure rate to 0.001999.

*Edit* 
The algorithm below is just $O(n)$ once bolts and holes are sorted, which is $O(n log(n))$.

You start from the largest bolts and fit them to the largest possible hole. If a bolt does not fit you reject it and switch to the next bolt.

It seems to me that this algorithm would be optimal.

However, I don't see how to derive the expected quantity of recalls analytically.

Comment: I am looking for analytical results. The simulation was just to show the expected effekt.

Comment: It seems to me that there are $n!$ possible pairings. Now you could start with the largest bolt and try fit it in the largest hole, if it does not work, reject that bolt and try to fit the second largest bolt into that same hole. Would this algorithm will match every bolt that does not need to be rejected and therefore be optimal?

Comment: How do you get $n!$ ?

Comment: bolt 1 can be linked to n possible holes, bolt 2 can be linked to n-1 ... leading to $n!$ possible permutations.